# Create a hash map without original key values

Tags: c++, hash

I have a file containing a list of couples. Each couple contains a 64 bit integer, that is an hash computed over a string, and a value that is an integer.

I want to load the list in a hash map in the main memory.
And then search values using the original string (I have the hash function).

For Example the file could be like:

```
keys values
78243536 12
38735342 20
32353498 18
```

if I want to search a term for example "pippo" I can use `hashfunction("pippo")`.

The question is: can I use `std::map` computed on these hash? How can I insert directly the hash values inside the map without having the original string?

Comment: Use the hash value as key? Then if you have a string you want to search for calculate its hash and use that hash to search in the map.

Comment: Use a `std::map<long, int>`?  Also worth thinking about is the uniqueness of the values produced by your hash function.

Comment: Yes it could be a possibility... but in practice I have to compute 2 hash any time I want to find a string... I only wanted to avoid this.

Comment: I have a feeling you're misunderstanding the purpose of the map/hashes. Can you please describe the *original* task in your question?

Answer (score 1):

A map is a mapping between keys of a given type and values. The interface of the map is defined in a way that you may either iterate through the whole map or search for a specific element using the key in the map. In your case you want to be able to search not by a key in the map but using another element that is somehow relevant to this key. You can not do this with bare map but you can create a helper function to handle that for you:

```
map<long long, int> my_map;

.... so some stuff ...

map<long long, int>::iterator find_by_string(const std::string& s) {
  return my_map.find(hash_code(s));
}
```

Comment: OK I'have already implemented this and it works.

My doubt was: there is a faster solution?

Comment: It can not possibly be faster. If you want to search using a string's hash code you need to compute it, after you've computed the hash you perform as best as an `std::map` can.If you use an `std::unordered_map` you will be able to have better complexity(because lookup is amortized constant vs `log(N)` for `std::map`).

Comment: As I said in my answer, there is no unique transform from hash back to string so you will be getting random results from time to time

Comment: @bobah indeed this is important to say.

Comment: I know I didn't want to go back to strings. Maybe you misunderstood my purpose. In theory it is possible to compute an hash_map using the hashkeys and the values. But it seems that is not possible to do that exploiting std::map.

Answer (score 0):

Hashing operation is irreversible (multiple strings can have the same hash value), so hash value cannot be used as a unique key and what you are trying to do is not possible.

Comment: A caveat:  it is possible if you are able to check all the strings you want to use in advance to verify that no two of them map to the same hash code.  (if the check finds that two strings do map to the same hash code, then you can handle that either by using a different hash function, omitting one of the two strings, or coming up with some other way to resolve the collision)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner - would you ever do it this way yourself? (I do accept though, your comment is making my answer more complete)

Comment: Probably not, because in most cases I don't need performance so much that I would worry about it.  The only scenario I can think of where it might be worth the effort is a program that has to run on a very slow CPU (e.g. a micro controller) that needs to deal with a fixed set of strings that are all known at compile-time.